# ¿Cómo introducir en una lista los coeficientes que devuelve el objeto glm?

Tags: r, dataframe, regresión-lineal

Supongamos que tenemos el dataframe llamado `datos_def` con datos sobre la Encuesta Nacional De Salud, donde cada variable es una pregunta de dicha encuesta. Se lleva a cabo un modelo logit binomial tal y como se aprecia en el siguiente código (La variable SAP es una variable binaria que toma valor 0 si la Salud Auto-Percibida es buena o muy buena, toma valor 1 si esta es mala o muy mala)

```
# Introducimos los datos del dataframe en un objeto subset()
datos_modelo<- subset(datos_def, select = c("SAP", "sexo", "edad", "peso","altura","niv_est","enf_cron",
                                            "fuma","sit_lab","frec_act_fis","estrato","ingreso_eq","GHQ_12"))
head(datos_modelo)

# Creamos el objeto que contiene los resultados del modelo
modelo_logit <- glm(SAP ~ sexo + edad + peso + altura + niv_est + enf_cron + fuma + sit_lab +
                       frec_act_fis + estrato  + ingreso_eq + GHQ_12, 
                     data = datos_modelo, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
# Resultados
summary(modelo_logit)
```

Lo que necesito es crear una lista con los coeficientes que devuelve `glm()`, así como otros resultados contenidos en el objeto `glm()`. He intentado lo siguiente pero sin éxito:
`coefs<-c(modelo_logit$coefficents)`

También he intentado llamar directamente a `modelo_logit$coefficents` pero me devuelve un valor nulo

Comment: Tienes un error tipografico no es `coefficents`sino `coefficients`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con las funciones accessor por ejemplo `coeficientes <- coefficients(modelo_logit)` otras son fitted.values, residuals, etc. y luego si las necesitas en una lista puedes armarla con list()

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero el error era el que comenta @pmoracho en mi pregunta.

Comment: SI es bastante común, suerte!